# Delphi Resizing Form messes up components

Tags: delphi, firedac

I created my form and it looks fine in the standard size when ran with the program, however when I maximize the form, the components get messed up. I anchored the components on the left and right, however a giant gap is created in the middle of the form and I don't know how to fix it. When in the 'Design' view of the program, all my components are touching from me trying to fill the middle gap. I tried aligning, anchoring and searched online for a while with no luck. Any clue?
Form in standard size upon running program:
[image: In the standard form size upon running program]

Form in full screen with giant middle gap:
[image: Full screen of the form. Random giant gap in mid]

Comment: What do you expect should happen?  What do you think it should look like instead of the "giant middle gap"?  What you're showing is expected behaviour so it's helpful to understand what you have in mind.  Are you trying to achieve a UI that keeps all font and layout proportions but scales **everything** with the window size?

Comment: "*I anchored the components on the left and right*" - HOW did you anchor them exactly? Which control has which settings? What you have shown makes sense if some of the controls are only anchored on the left, and some are only anchored on the right. Can you provide the DFM?

Comment: I would hope that it would scale evenly on the panel when expanded(excluding aligned items), similar to how it looks when not maximized. I aligned the two far left buttons to alLeft and the far right button to alRight; all three are anchored with [akLeft,akTop,akBottom]. Everything between that is anchored with [akTop,akRight].

Comment: That's not what `Anchor` means. Anchoring the control to the right means that it stays at a fixed position from the right edge. When the form is resized and becomes wider, right-anchored controls stick to the right edge and move with it. The same applies in reverse to left-anchored controls. Consider dropping an anchor from a ship, which is where the name `Anchor` camel from. What you want is to **not** anchor the controls, which allows the form to position them as needed as it resizes.

Comment: Awesome! I'll give it a shot! thanks for the help

Comment: So I tried it, however no I get the issue of when I scale the window, the gaps between the components increase. Hmmm

Comment: Of course they do. What would you expect to happen? You either anchor them (in which case you end up with the big gap in the middle) or you allow them to scale (in which case they spread out evenly). What other behavior would you expect? What do you think should happen?

Comment: You haven't told us which version of Delphi you're using, or what other constraints you have, but it sounds like you'd be much better off using FMX instead of VCL, if not already. The VCL does not support any type of arbitrary scaling of UI components but [FMX does](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_Layouts_to_Create_a_Scaled_Effect), specifically using a [TScaledLayout](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.Layouts.TScaledLayout)

Comment: Panels and the Align property are your friend here. Just put your controls on panels, and set the Align property for the panels correct. Also, it often is best to first put one larger panel and put all other panels on that one. I never had to write any code for keeping my controls on the desired position, until now I always got by very easy by using panels and the Align property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the form's `OnResize` event, you can compute the `width` and `left` property values for the component to fit the new size. You can adjust the width of components or distribute the distance between components to get the look you want. Or a combination of the two.

It is also possible to put the components on two lines if the form's width becomes too small. Or use a scroll panel so that the user can scroll to see what is not possible to show correctly given the width.

All that requires coding. Parts can be done using panels and align the panels.